# Understanding Rails app initialization on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I'm trying to get a handle on how/when Rails apps are initialized in Heroku...

### Example 1

For example, let's say I add the following log action at the very beginning of my app:

**in config/application.rb:**

```
module Tester
  class Application < Rails::Application

    test_logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)
    test_logger.info('STARTING APP - VERSION 1')
```

If I then run my app locally I'll see that log message right away:

```
$ rails server
INFO -- : STARTING APP - VERSION 1
```

Great. Now let's push to Heroku:

```
git push heroku master
```

The app deploys and starts. But looking at the Papertrail logs, there's no message.

Ok, so I try restarting the app:

```
heroku restart
```

and now the log message *does* show up.

Next, I increment the version number and push up to Heroku again. This time, I see the log message, but showing 'VERSION 1' instead of 'VERSION 2'. This consistently happens on subsequent pushes- it will always show a log message that's one version behind. If I restart the app, the log message version is current. Anyone know why this is so?

### Example 2

I set an ENV value via the Heroku CLI:
heroku config:set TEST_VAR=something

and put code in my application.rb file to read it:
module Tester
  class Application < Rails::Application

```
config.before_configuration do
  test_logger.info(ENV['TEST_VALUE'])
end
```

When I deploy to Heroku, the call is hit twice. The first time, it gets logged to my terminal screen, and the ENV variable doesn't exist. The second time, it gets logged to Heroku's system (visible in my Papertrail dashboard) and the variable does exist. Why the double-pass, and is there a way to distinguish between those different instances in code?