# Do something after Heroku deployment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

Is there a hook or event that can be used in order to trigger something immediately after a Rails app is deployed to Heroku?

Specifically, we want to build out a certain directory structure under tmp/ (the structure is contingent on config values so it can't be checked into source).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Heroku supports a few after deploy hooks - see https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploy-hooks .
You can use the HTTP hook to trigger an action on your app which will create your desired structure. As an example of how to use this HTTP deploy hook, check out http://dzello.com/blog/2012/03/11/spin-up-your-heroku-dyno-automatically-after-deploy/

Keep in mind though that if you build anything in the `tmp` directory, it'll go away after a dyno restart.

Comment: @eugen- thanks for this- Giving you credit because you answered the first part BUT also pointed out that what Im trying to achieve actually wouldn't work on a deploy hook. [My answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21652889/165673) provides a solution/hack for the second part...

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the two parts of my question are not compatible- @eugen explains how to implement a post-deploy hook, but also reminded me that any tmp directories I create will be blown out whenever a dyno restarts...

So what's the solution? The following is what I came up with:

**config/initializers/setup.rb**

```
# Ensure temp file system is set up:
begin
  Dir.mkdir("tmp/customdir") unless File.exists?("tmp/customdir")
rescue StandardError => e
  # Allow this to fail on initial deploy 
  # (It will raise error: "No such file or directory - tmp/customdir" because the tmp dir won't yet exist)
end
```

**Explanation:**
Heroku essentially does a two-pass initialization during deploys. The first pass, when it pre-compiles assets, would normally choke on the above code because the tmp directory will not yet exist. If we allow it to fail, it will work on the second pass, and on subsequent restarts.

Yeah it's a hack. I've [tried before](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19030110/165673) to figure out how to distinguish between a pre-compile initialization and normal initializations, but there doesn't seem to be a way, so this is what we're left with.

If anyone can improve on this would love to hear it.