# Dynamically generating a clock file (or any file) during Rails deployment on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, clockwork

I use the [Clockwork](https://github.com/tomykaira/clockwork) gem to schedule jobs on my Rails app deployed with Heroku.

For the unfamiliar, it basically reads from a `clock.rb` file in your app root..

```
# config.rb

# Schedule every Monday @ 13:00 UTC
every(1.week, "some description", at: "Monday 13:00", tz: "UTC"){
  `rake clock_tasks:my_task`
}
```

... and there's a dedicated Dyno that runs the clock process.

```
# Procfile
...
clock: bundle exec clockwork clock.rb
...
```

Well what if I didn't want to hard-code the clock file? I'd love to be able to generate the `clock.rb` dynamically using ERB at app startup. This gives me the flexibility to schedule or not schedule certain tasks based of Environment configurations, etc...

1. Does Heroku allow you to "write" a file at any point to your local filesystem so I can generated and write the `clock.rb` file during an initializer step?
2. Is there a way to delay the execution of starting the dyno with the `bundle exec` command until AFTER I've created the `clock.rb` file? I could start off with a fake/empty file and then populate a new one during initializer, but I'd still need a way for clock to pick it up again by restarting the `bundle exec clockwork...` command.

Any other creative solutions appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: I think a more sane solution is to use env vars in your `clock.rb` file.

Comment: That's a fair solution for a small implementation. For larger more dynamic implementations we don't want to pile up the use of 100+ ENV variables or have logic like "if ENV variables == foo, add this". The heart of the question is whether Heroku *can* support something like this.

Comment: You can write files to your heroku slug at runtime, thats not the problem. Dynamically generating the file sounds like a risky proposition - you lose the peace of mind of knowing that the code you pushed is the code actually running. And since Heroku does not offer direct shell access its difficult to see what the code running actually is. If your project really is large as you say than maybe you should define the tasks as service objects or models and make them end user toggleable either by env vars or a  UI.

Comment: Plus heroku actually has plugins to run scheduled jobs - so using clockwork just might be the clunkiest way possible to solve the issue. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduler

Comment: It's ruby code, how much more dynamic can it be? I'm having trouble imagining anything you could do more easily if it were erb...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do something after Heroku deployment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21652207/do-something-after-heroku-deployment)

Comment: Why do you think `ERB` would be easier than plain Ruby? You need the same conditions coming from the outside as ENV variables and you can hardcode the same configurations in both cases. What do you think makes it any different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You `config.rb` is just Ruby. There is no need for `ERB`, plain Ruby in combination with `ENV` variables should be enough to solve you problem:

```
# Schedule every `ENV['schedule_time']` (with fallback if empty)
schedule_time = ENV['schedule_time'].presence || 'Monday 13:00'
every(1.week, "some description", at: schedule_time, tz: "UTC") {
  `rake clock_tasks:my_task`
}
```

Or you can write something like this:

```
if ENV[`foo`]
  # config bar
else
  # config baz
end
```

You may want to read [Configuration and Config Vars](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars) about how to set and read environment variables on Heroku.